# «Раздача статического содержимого»

Tags: nginx

https://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html

Там есть тема: «Раздача статического содержимого», и там написано:

> Во-первых, создайте каталог `/data/www` и положите в него файл `index.html` с любым текстовым содержанием, а также создайте каталог `/data/images` и положите в него несколько файлов с изображениями.

`/data/www` и `/data/images` - здесь имеются ввиду главный каталог nginx? или любой ? + /user (домашний каталог пользователя)?

Comment: Любой; у nginx нет «главного каталога»

Comment: Понял, но веб-сервер выдает ошибку: "404 Not Found"

Comment: http://localhost/data/www/index.html - "404 Not Found"

Comment: Потому что  случае `location /` адрес будет соответственно http://localhost/index.html

Comment: Тоесть нужно переписать на: location /data/www ?

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы работал адрес http://localhost/data/www/index.html то пишите `location /data/www/ { alias /data/www; }`

Comment: Понял, чтобы это настройка работала нужно перезапустить сервер правильно, но пишу:  ---nginx -s reload--- то пишет это:                                                                           nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:86

Comment: Исправляйте указанную ошибку, что тут ещё сказать